# Snakemake run rule in order

Tags: snakemake

I am using snakemake to run my pipeline.

```
rule fisrt_rule:
    input: "{sample}/path/to/{sample}.txt"
    output: "{sample}/path/to/{sample}.stat"
    shell:
        """
        do something
        """
        
rule next_rule:
    input:
        folder="{sample}/path/to/",
    output:
        raw="{sample}/path/to/{sample}.raw.txt"
    shell:
        """
        do something
        """
```

In the `next_rule` the software wants only the folder where the files are and not the file name, but since snakemake does not take as input the previous rule it says that the `files do not exist`. Is there a way to tell snakemake to run a rule in order without necessary taking the previous output as input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the directory name within the shell script:

```
rule next_rule:
    input:
        folder= "{sample}/path/to/{sample}.stat",
    output:
        raw= "{sample}/path/to/{sample}.raw.txt"
    shell:
        """
        folder=`dirname {input.folder}`
        do something $folder
        """
```

> Is there a way to tell snakemake to run a rule in order without necessary taking the previous output as input?

Maybe you could come up with some logic to do that but I think you would go against the purpose and design principles of snakemake.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I will now try your suggestion. For now I added a params: outdir= "{sample}/path/to" to the next_rule, seems to be working. So basically in my understanding this is not so straighforward in snakemake.

Comment: @user3224522 using `params` you have to make sure that the string `outdir= "{sample}/path/to"` is consistent with the rule that generated it. I mean, there is a bit of duplication- if you change one you have to remember to change also the other.

Comment: Regarding rule execution order, I think it's good that snakemake doesn't give you much freedom since in this way you are pretty sure that output is always consistent and up-to-date with the input.

Comment: Don't worry - it's not important. If I get a bit of time I'll try to explain it better but it's no biggie!